# List index out of range in 'file' object -- Python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a text file `reval2_log.txt`, which contains data like

```
yield_curve on;DATE_val 2013 12 31;arion on;INFL_filn /srv/www/tbg/file/1/2014-07-21/Vaxtaferlar_nidur.csv;ASSETS_filn /srv/www/tbg/file/1/2014-07-21/Vordur_VT.xls;REVAL_filn kfjh.xls;CPI_value 416.7;LSK_value 8022.3;YIELDC_filn /srv/www/tbg/file/1/2014-07-21/infl.csv;CASHF_filn weouhf.xls;sjf on;user 1
```

I then do this:

```
f = open('reval2_log.txt', 'r')
read = f.readlines()[0].split(";")
```

And it returns an `IndexError`. Python of course can find the file, because it doesn't return a "file not found" error (and it does if I garble the filename).

Trace:

```
File "/srv/www/tbg/notendur/views.py" in reikna_reval2
  79.       reval2.main(user)
File "/srv/www/tbg/calc/reval2.py" in main
  322.  read = f.readlines()[0].split(";")

Exception Type: IndexError at /notendur/reikna/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Comment: Why do you use `.readlines()` just to get the first line? Why not use `f.readline()` (singular) instead? `f.readline().split(';')`.

Comment: Good catch, that is more sensible of course. I'll change that

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: @Firkamon: does it still generate an `IndexError` now? Because if your file is *empty*, `.readlines()` returns an empty list, and there is no item at index 0..

Comment: No, it appears not. The list is still empty, though, despite the file not being empty

Comment: The list is still empty, though, despite the file not being empty

Comment: Are you sure the file you're looking at and the file your program is opening are the same file?

Comment: Yes, there are three files called reval2_log.txt on the server, and they all have an identical data format (semicommas for separation).

Answer (score 0):

Martijn's suggestion to use readline() is good. If your input can be empty at times, then you can try this:

```
read = f.read().split(";")
```